# How does a call to major function specified in DriverObject can look like?

Tags: c, winapi, kernel, driver

Consider I create driver and I specify major functions:

```
  DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE] = ctlCreateClose;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CLOSE] = ctlCreateClose;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL] = ctlDeviceControl;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_READ] = ctlDeviceGet;
    DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_WRITE] = ctlDevicePut;
    DriverObject->DriverUnload = ctlUnloadDriver;
```

Everything works as expected, however I have no idea how to call IRP_MJ_WRITE, could you please show me how to do such call? I wanna know why because I'm working in a project and I can not find where is this specific majorfunction called (even with debbugger help).

Comment: @aco You'll find the definition for the `DRIVER_OBJECT` structure [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_driver_object).

Comment: *how to call IRP_MJ_WRITE* - open file on your device and call `WriteFile`

Answer (score 1):

After you create a device object in your driver using `IoCreateDevice` or `IoCreateDeviceSecure`, A user-mode process can use the `CreateFile` API and pass the name of your device, and in this case your `IRP_MJ_CREATE` callback gets called. If that call returns successful, a handle is returned to that user-mode process. Afterwards the user-mode process can use the `WriteFile` API with that handle to invoke your `IRP_MJ_WRITE` callback, `ReadFile` API to invoke your `IRP_MJ_READ` callback, And `DeviceIoControl` API to invoke your `IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL` callback.

More info:

https://blog.nviso.eu/2021/11/30/kernel-karnage-part-5-i-o-callbacks